# iOS: Data Driven Drilldown Reference App

Tags: ios, xcode, viewcontroller, drilldown

I'm looking to create a reference app for iOS that drills-down through categories to display a Detail viewcontroller containing the topic information.

I've been studying Xcode for a while but can't quite find the advice I need to focus my study in this area.

The drill-down will be, at most, 5 levels. What is the best database technology to use for something quite low level?

What should I be targeting in my searches to find tutorials that can help me in this specific area?

Comment: I should note that the data will exist on the device and doesn't need to communicate with the net

Answer (score 0):

Use Core Data backed by a SQL or XML repository. Many tutorials on the Apple sites as well as other sites.